# GDPR: Firebase and Admob

Tags: firebase, admob

I had an app that used basic Firebase Analytics and AdMob. While I can't recompile the APK because I don't have the source code anymore. I was afraid that it might not be GDPR compliant, so I removed the ad-banner in the AdMob console and deleted the Firebase project. Now I don't see any data, but the code is still in the app.

Is this GDPR compliant?

Comment: I think the issue here is that the data may be still being collected and third parties are now alone with it. Depending on where your app is availale and where people are really using it, you could just stop letting it availbale in countries where the regulation applies whether it doesn't make your app totally unusable.

Comment: @JorgeAmVF The app is totally usable without firebase nur admob. Disabling it in europe isnt a solution since it's purpose is to show the busses in my country and 95% of users are from this country, the rest probably uses a VPN and appear like they aren't. But now that I'm not in charge of this data (I can't even access it), wouldn't google be responsible for it?

Comment: Oh, I get it. I have a similar project under development and it's really unthinkable. I think you might be right about your line of reasoning, but I'm not sure if you'd really be out of the situation if an issue pops up because the data comes from your app (I don't believe anything may happen though). To be totally safe here the best way would be to get rid of the app whether you don't care about it, but you could totally prepare yourself to defend your position in case something happens. You could try to contact the third parties so as to ask them about the best solution and to show goodwill.

Comment: Maybe you can decompile your own apk, change a few lines of code and then re-assemble the apk.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about legal compliance rather than programming as defined by the Help Center. Please ask legal questions on https://law.stackexchange.com instead.